# preg_replace all occurrences in string withing defined delimeters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace all occurrences of "**a**" with "**b**" inside some string. Problem is that I need to replace only those letters which are inside brackets:

> asd asd asd **[asd asd asd]** asd asd asd

For now I have this code:

```
$what = '/(?<=\[)a(?=.*?\])/s';
$with = 'b';
$where = 'asd asd asd [asd asd asd] asd asd asd';
```

But it only replaces the first "a", and I am getting this result:

> asd asd asd **[bsd asd asd]** asd asd asd

I realy need to done this only with one preg_replace call.

Comment: I would first match the bracketed areas and do a simple `strtr()` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a single `preg_replace` call because the lookbehind would need to say "there is an opening square bracket *somewhere* before the match" and that is impossible since lookbehind patterns must have fixed length.

Why would you absolutely *need* to do this in one call anyway? It is doable pretty easily with `preg_replace_callback`, where you would match groups of content inside square brackets and use `preg_replace` on the match each time (or just a simple `str_replace` if all you are going to do is replace "a" with "b").

Example:

```
$what = '/\[([^]]*)\]/';
$where = 'asd asd asd [asd asd asd] asd asd asd';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    $what, 
    function($match) {
        return '['.str_replace('a', 'b', $match[1]).']';
    },
    $where);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (This what exactly Jon explained)

```
function replace_a_with_b($matches)
{
  return str_replace("a", "b", $matches[0]);
}
$text = 'asd asd asd [asd asd asd] asd asd asd';
echo preg_replace_callback("#(\[[^]]+\])#", "replace_a_with_b", $text);
```

Output:

```
asd asd asd [bsd bsd bsd] asd asd asd
```