# PHP preg_replace all matches

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all matches with using `preg_replace` but it only works once.

Here is function i used:

```
function bbc2html($text) {
    $find = array(
        '~\[spoiler\](.*?)\[/spoiler\]~s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<font color="red"><b>ATTENTION: SPOILER ALARM!</b></font><br>$1'
    );
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

Input:

```
echo bbc2html('[spoiler]Its a spoiler[/spoiler]');
echo bbc2html('[spoiler][spoiler]Its a multiple spoiler[/spoiler][/spoiler]');
```

Output:

```
<font color="red"><b>ATTENTION: SPOILER ALARM!</b></font><br>Its a spoiler
<font color="red"><b>ATTENTION: SPOILER ALARM!</b></font><br>[spoiler]Its a multiple spoiler[/spoiler]
```

Comment: toss it in a while loop or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445296/preg-replace-all-occurrences-in-string-withing-defined-delimeters

Comment: @chris85 im sorry i forgot that, i added now

Comment: Okay, so you have layered tags. You should use a bbcode parser, not a regex.

Comment: I want use custom tags. Am i have use this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php

Comment: Well, perhaps, [`'~(?:\[spoiler\])+(.*?)(?:\[/spoiler\])+~s'`](https://regex101.com/r/LY8jHl/2) will work here. It won't work if the `[spoiler]` tags are not consecutive though. Anyway, a parser would be much better.

Comment: Its didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bbc2html($text) {
$find = array(
    '~(\[spoiler\])+(.*?)(\[/spoiler\])+~s'
);
$replace = array(
    '<font color="red"><b>ATTENTION: SPOILER ALARM!</b></font><br>$2'
);
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

Does it work?

Comment: It couldn't help but im found the solution. I'm using this class: https://github.com/samclarke/SBBCodeParser

Comment: I did but it don't help, i'm using function you wrote and `text` is `echo bbc2html2('[spoiler]asdas[spoiler]Its a multiple spoiler[/spoiler][/spoiler]');`

Comment: of course useless , because your first demo is `'[spoiler][spoiler]...'` , but now changed to `'[spoiler]asdas[spoiler]...'` , so , you'd change the function to  
```function bbc2html($text) {
    $find = array(
        '~(\[spoiler\]\w*)+(.*?)(\[/spoiler\])+~s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<font color="red"><b>ATTENTION: SPOILER ALARM!</b></font><br>$2'
    );
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}```

Answer (score 0):

this is another function:

```
function bbc2html($text) {
$find = array(
    '~(\[spoiler\]\w*)+(.*?)(\[/spoiler\])+~s'
);
$replace = array(
    '<font color="red"><b>ATTENTION: SPOILER ALARM!</b></font><br>$2'
);
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```